# Projeto C# fechando o Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memória, reportviewer

Recentemente fiz um projeto Console Application que salva arquivos PDF com Report Viewer e funcionava normalmente.

precisei alterar a procedure SQL Server que gera esses arquivos e mudei o diretório para salvar esses arquivos, até ai nada demais, porém, a aplicação vai funcionando normalmente e salvando os arquivos até que ela se encerra de repente e ainda fecha o Visual Studio (2013) sem demonstrar erro ou exceção aparente.

Essa aplicação é famosa por usar muita memória RAM, cerca de 1.5GB de RAM, por salvar relatórios com alto grau de complexividade. Talvez o gerenciador de processos esteja encerrando o processo do Visual Studio mas, não sei como impedir isso.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Fez o teste em uma máquina mais potente? Não precisa de muito já que o Visual Studio é 32bits

Comment: então cara, eu tentei executar no VS mas, continua dando o mesmo problema, porém, quando eu compilo o projeto e instalo na maquina ele funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Já passei por algo parecido, no meu caso era uma extensão que estava fazendo isso.

Primeiro de tudo verificaria a aplicação, se ela possui exceções não tratadas, memory leak dentre outros.. mas se está rodando perfeitamente no cliente pode ser sim um problema na sua IDE/Ambiente.

Desabilite todas as extensões, ex: Reshaper, OZCode, Codemaid etc.. principalmente as que carregam componentes para Debug (tipo OzCode) ajuda bastante, mas acaba pesando e pode ser um motivo da sua IDE ter problemas.

Faça atualizações do VisualStudio e o sistema operacional.

Se for possível migre para uma versão mais nova do VisualStudio e teste.

Comment: então cara, eu desabilitei as extensões, re-instalei o VS e continuou fechando sozinho. para funcionar, precisei publicar o projeto e executar pelo instalador, assim ele vai até o final sem fechar :(

Comment: cara.. estranho mesmo! Por curiosidade você tá usando qual versão do VS?

Comment: VS 2013 Professional, conversei com o cara que iniciou o projeto e descobri que esse erro acontece sempre nesse projeto, até em outras maquinas isso acontece, agora não sei dizer se é problema do VS ou não

Comment: Você consegue testar no VS Community recente? O Visual Studio é famoso por ter bastantes bugs (com todo respeito ao pessoal da MS). De 2013 para cá (~ 7 anos) com certeza houve muitas correções. Assim como o Win 7 as versões antigas perdem suporte, sendo recomendado migrar para as versões mais novas (Acredito que o suporte da MS vai te responder algo assim).